# PHP script is having trouble sending email correctly

Tags: php, scripting

Below is my scripting for my submit form. I'm getting the email, but all it contains is the IP address and time stamp. I am not receiving any of the other information listed. I'm very new to PHP, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, in the email, it is saying from `d91b8401`, `d91b8401@p3nlhg1159.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net`. Is there a way to correct that?

```
<?php
include('database/config.php');
include('database/database.php');

$err = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){        

    $first = addslashes(trim($_POST['first'])); 

    $last = addslashes(trim($_POST['last']));   

    $glvar = addslashes(trim($_POST['glvar']));

    $ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    //echo $ip;

     if(($first!='')&& ($last!='')&& ($glvar!='')){ 

        $database = new Database(HOST, DATEBASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);   

        $allUsers = $database->select('user','glvar_id','*',"glvar_id = '".$glvar."'");
        //echo $ip;     

        $checkglvar = 0;            
    $checkglvar = count($allUsers); 

        $userData = array(              
            'first_name' => $first, 
            'last_name' => $last,               
            'glvar_id' => $glvar,       
            'ip' => $ip,        

        );      

        if(!$checkglvar) {          

            $database->insert('user',$userData);

            $message = "First Name: $first";
            $message = "Last Name: $last";
            $message = "GLVAR ID: $glvar";
            $message = "IP: $ip" . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= "TIME: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            mail("info@lvrealestateagentssignthepetition.com", "New Petition Signer", $message);

            header('location:thank-you.html');      

        }    else  $err.='<p style="color:red">Ooops! You have already signed the petition</p>';        

    } else {    

        if($first=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your First Name is empty</p>';   

        if($last=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your Last Name is empty</p>'; 

        if($glvar=='') $err.='<p style="color:red">Your GLVAR ID is empty</p>'; 

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Personally I think you're missing `header information`. You have `mail("info@lvrealestateagentssignthepetition.com", "New Petition Signer", $message);` - should look something like this `mail("info@lvrealestateagentssignthepetition.com", "New Petition Signer", $message, $headers);` - adding **$headers** after **$message**. Then adding something like `$headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";` at the top of your script.

Comment: The reason you're getting `d91b8401, d91b8401@p3nlhg1159.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net` back as the `From:`, is just that, there is **no** `From:` in your headers.

Comment: Plus the concatenating dots in `message = "...`. 2nd, 3rd and 4th should show as `message .= "...`. Ok, I'm off to "Lah-Lah Land".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.=` to append to the message, you're just replacing it with each assignment.

```
        $message = "First Name: $first";
        $message .= "Last Name: $last";
        $message .= "GLVAR ID: $glvar";
        $message .= "IP: $ip" . PHP_EOL;
        $message .= "TIME: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can change the `From:` address with:

```
mail("info@lvrealestateagentssignthepetition.com", "New Petition Signer", $message, "From: yourname@yourdomain.com");
```

The fourth argument is optional headers, which override the default headers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple mail code segment You can change/Use according your need:::

```
$to = "sujeet.kumar@xyz.kk";
$subject = "Test Mail";

$message = "Hi Sujeet, A user of your site is Contacted you. ";

$headers = "From: sujeet@g.kk";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
alert("Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.");
//-->
</script>

<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this part:

```
        $message = "First Name: $first";
        $message = "Last Name: $last";
        $message = "GLVAR ID: $glvar";
        $message = "IP: $ip" . PHP_EOL;
        $message .= "TIME: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You're not adding any information to $message. Instead you're overwriting it everytime, except for the last time. Use the `.=` operator for the other additions as well.

Comment: isn't your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th in need of a dot? as in `$message .=`?

Comment: Ah.... I see now, you're suggesting it "under" what the OP wrote in the first place. Didn't notice that till now. I really need to get some sleep. *"Are those spiders running down my wall?"*